# what does "aa" in for statement in Python do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

```
def pdf_exp(lamb,x):
    return lamb*np.exp(-1*lamb*x)

likelihood1 = 1
likelihood2 = 2
for aa in data[1].values:
  likelihood1 = likelihood1*pdf_exp(lamb=1,x=aa)
  likelohood2 = likelihood2*pdf_exp(lamb=2,x=aa)
log_likelihood1 = np.log(likelihood1)
log_likelihood2 = np.log(likelihood2)

print(log_likelihood1 - log_likelihood2)
```

The 'data' is a n*2 array with with 2nd column as random variables. The above code was used to find the likelihood. 
In the "for" statement what does "aa" do ?

Comment: It's just the loop variable, it takes the value of each item `in data[1].values` in turn.

Comment: `aa` isn't a statement, it's a variable. The statement is the `for` statement, which loops over all elements in the list `data[1].values`. Each iteration the variable `aa` will have the value of the next element in the list.

Comment: Thanks, you all. I got it.